# When I change the quantity of my products in my shopping cart, the total price doesn't change (PHP)

Tags: php, html, html-table

When I change the quantity of my products, the total price at the bottom of the page doesn't change. When I increase or decrease the quantity, the total must automatically change. Please help me

```
// Shopping cart page

<?php
    include_once 'Dao/shoppingCartDao.php';

    $shoppingCartItem = shoppingCartDao::getShoppingCartItems();

    foreach ($shoppingCartItem as $item) {

?>

<tr>
    <td><a href="detail.php?productId=<?php echo $item->getProductId(); ?>"><img src="./img/<?php echo $item->getProduct()->getImage(); ?>"></a></td>
    <td><?php echo $item->getProduct()->getName(); ?></td>
    <td>&euro; <?php echo $item->getTotalPriceExclVAT(); ?><small> (Excl. VAT)</small></td>
    <td>&euro; <?php echo $item->getTotalPriceInclVAT(); ?><small> (Incl. VAT)</small></td>
    <td>
        <form action="" method="POST">
          <input type="hidden" name="postcheck" value="true">
          <input id="number" type="number" min="0" max="20" step="1" value ="<?php echo $item->getAantal(); ?>"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="productId" value="<?php echo $item->getProductId() ?>">
          <td><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update"></td>                               
        </form>

        <form action="deleteItem.php" method="POST">
           <input type="hidden" name="postcheck" value="true">
           <input type="hidden" name="productId" value="<?php echo $item->getProductId() ?>">
           <td><input type="submit" name="deleteItem" value="Delete"></td>                               
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>

<?php
    }
?>

<div>
       <div>
            <div><strong>Total Price (Excl. VAT)</strong></div>
            <div><strong>Total Price (Incl. VAT)</strong></div>
            <div><strong>VAT</strong></div>
            <div>&euro; <?php echo shoppingCartDao::getTotalPriceExclVAT(); ?></div>
            <div>&euro; <?php echo shoppingCartDao::getTotalPriceInclVAT(); ?></div>
            <div>&euro; <?php echo shoppingCartDao::getTotalVAT(); ?></div>
      </div>
</div>
```

[image: Explanation, using an image]

Comment: So the price should be updated on the client side? Then you have to implement an onChange listener to your quantity input field.

Comment: The intention is that when the quantity changes, the total price changes automatically

Comment: I understood this, however, please be more precise about WHEN this should change. Right when the user enters a new number? Or does he have to submit a form first? For the first case, you need an onChange listener as already stated

Comment: Submit a form first

Comment: So please provide the form you are using. I can only see a form for deleting items. There is no code for submitting the new quantity to the server and the server does not seem to handle any quantity information provided by the client...

Comment: Well, please edit your question accordingly. It seems you're submitting to the same page, but in your php code you do not handle the form data.

Comment: The thing is, I don't want to click on a submit button when I change the quantity. I want the price to be updated on the server side, but I don't know how

Comment: Ok, I will create an answer based on what I guess you want to achieve ;)

Answer (score 1):

So from the comments I deduce that you want the following:

- You have a shopping cart where the user can change the amount of each item by entering a number or clicking the up/down arrows of the number input
- Whenever the amont is changed, the frontend should update and further, the server should apply the new amount to the shopping cart for later use and / or checkout.
- You don't want the user to have to press a submit button or to refresh the page every time a new amount has been entered.

To achieve this, you should create a dedicated php script that changes the amount on server side and responds with the new amount and the resulting price.

`updateQuantity.php`

```php
$productId = $_POST["productId"];
$quantity = $_POST["quantity"];

// Add error handling, authentication, ...
// ...
// Set the new quantity on server side
// This is just an example, the functions might not be existent!
$shoppingCartItem = shoppingCartDao::getShoppingCartItem($productId); 
$success = $shoppingCartItem->setAantal($quantity);

$response = [
    "success" => $success,
    "productId" => $productId,
    "quantity" => $shoppingCartItem->getAantal(),
    "exclVAT" => $shoppingCartItem->getTotalPriceExclVAT(),
    "inclVAT" => $shoppingCartItem->getTotalPriceInclVAT()
];
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

From your client side website, you can then use an AJAX request to update the quantity.
First, give your number input an id or a data attribute

```php
echo '<input id="number" class="productQuantity" type="number" min="0" max="20" step="1" value ="'.$item->getAantal().'" data-product="'.$item->getProductId().'"/>';
```

and then add an onChange listener (or whatever listener satisfies your needs):

```
$(".productQuantity").on("change", function() {
    var productId = $(this).data("product");
    var quantity = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "updateQuantity.php",
        data: {
            productId: productId,
            quantity: quantity
        },
        success: function(resp) {
            // Maybe check if the resp.quantity is the same as the desired quantity, otherwise reset the input field
            if (resp.success) {
                // Seems to be successful...
                // Update prices
                $("...").text(resp.exclVAT);
                $("...").text(resp.inclVAT);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

This should help you to get it working. It's no copy-pastable code, though.